# Serializing std::list into json with boost ptree

Tags: c++, json, serialization, boost, boost-propertytree

okay, so I am banging my head on this for last couple of days but still I am unable to get it right. I have a std::list container and I want to serialize it into JSON string so that I can send it over network.

**NOTE:** I compile my code using following:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o main main.cpp DBAccess11.cpp -lsqlite3 -lboost_serialization
```

I took help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394472/serializing-and-deserializing-json-with-boost) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832694/boostptree-parser-cant-read-the-container-from-the-xml-file)

Below is my **DBAccess1.h** file.

```
#ifndef DBAccess1_HH  
#define DBAccess1_HH

#include <list> // I have deleted some header for sake of readability
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

using namespace std;
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
using boost::property_tree::read_json;
using boost::property_tree::write_json;
using boost::property_tree::basic_ptree;

//================================//   
struct SiteCode
{
      int siteID;
      int siteCode;
};

inline ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, SiteCode &site)
{
    out << "(" << site.siteID << "," << site.siteCode << ")";
    return out;
}
//================================//

class sqliteDB {
    list<SiteCode> Site_Code_list;
public:
    list<SiteCode> GET_ALL_Site_Code();
    void printList();
};
#endif**
```

Below is the **DBAccess11.cpp** file where all the functions are defined

```
#include <list> // I have deleted some header for sake of readability
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
#include "DBAccess1.h"

using boost::property_tree::ptree;
using boost::property_tree::read_json;
using boost::property_tree::write_json;
using boost::property_tree::basic_ptree;

list<SiteCode> sqliteDB::GET_ALL_Site_Code()
{
        sqlite3 *db;
        const char *sql;
        sqlite3_stmt * stmt;

        int rc = sqlite3_open("/path/to/database.db", &db);
        sql = "SELECT * FROM SiteCode;";       
        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, 0);

    while(sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_ROW) {

            int A  = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
            int B = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 1);

            SiteCode info;
            info.siteID = A;
            info.siteCode = B;              

            cout<<"Preparing to push data into List"<<endl;
            Site_Code_list.push_back(info);
            cout<<"Data was pushed successfully"<<endl;

            ptree pt;
            for (auto& entry: list<SiteCode> Site_Code_list)  //<< ERROR LINE80
            pt.put(entry.siteID, entry.siteCode);
            std::ostringstream buf; 
            write_json (buf, pt, false); 
            cout<< buf.str() << endl;
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return Site_Code_list;
}
//====================================================//
void sqliteDB::printList()
{
     int s = Site_Code_list.size();
     cout << "The size of List is :" << s << endl;
     for( list<SiteCode> :: iterator it = Site_Code_list.begin(); it !=  Site_Code_list.end(); it++)     
     cout << *it << " ";
}
```

Below is **main.cpp**

```
#include <list> // I have deleted some header for sake of readability
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

using namespace std;
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
using boost::property_tree::read_json;
using boost::property_tree::write_json;
using boost::property_tree::basic_ptree;

int main()
{
    sqliteDB object1;
    object1.GET_ALL_Site_Code();
    object1.printList();
    cout << "\n\nAll the statement were executed properly\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
DBAccess11.cpp: In member function ‘std::list<SiteCode> sqliteDB::GET_ALL_Site_Code()’:
DBAccess11.cpp:80:38: error: expected primary-expression before ‘Site_Code_list’
 for (auto& entry: list<SiteCode> Site_Code_list)
                                  ^
DBAccess11.cpp:80:38: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Site_Code_list’
DBAccess11.cpp:80:52: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
 for (auto& entry: list<SiteCode> Site_Code_list)
                                                ^
```

My Questions:

(1)Is this the right way to convert **std::list into JSON** using boost ? if NO then how should it be done ? 
(Note- I can only use boost and no other library )

(2) If my approach is right then what changes shall I make to correct it ?

Comment: Should be just for (auto& entry: Site_Code_list)

Comment: @ForEveR: I did tried that already. I get following error. DBAccess11.cpp:80:40: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >::add(int&, int&)’
     pt.add(entry.siteID, entry.siteCode);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths in your tree are always strings. The compiler will tell you this in the remainder of the message. Arguably the documentation is a more readable source:

> Both `key_type` and `data_type` are configurable, but will usually be `std::string` [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/property_tree.html#boost_propertytree.intro)

> The [`self_type & put(const path_type & path, const Type & value, Translator tr);`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html#idp224701472-bb)

So the essence of the fix is

```
pt.put(std::to_string(entry.id), entry.code);
```

I got a little bit side-tracked cleaning up the code, so here goes:

<kbd>Self Contained Sample</kbd>

```
// FILE: some header
#include <ostream>

struct SiteCode {
    int id;
    int code;

    SiteCode(int id, int code) : id(id), code(code)
    { }

    friend inline std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, SiteCode const& site) {
        return out << "(" << site.id << "," << site.code << ")";
    }
};

#include <list> // I have deleted some header for sake of readability

// FILE: sqliteDB header
class sqliteDB {
    using Records = std::list<SiteCode>;
    Records _records;

  public:
    void load();
    Records const& get() const { return _records; }
    void printList() const;
    void writeJson(std::ostream& os) const;
};

// FILE: some sqlpp.hpp utility header (inline implementations only)
#include <memory>
#include <sqlite3.h>

namespace sqlpp {
    using database  = std::shared_ptr<::sqlite3>;

    void perror(int rc) {
        if (rc != SQLITE_OK) throw std::runtime_error(::sqlite3_errstr(rc));
    }

    struct statement {
        static statement prepare(database db, std::string const& sql) {
            ::sqlite3_stmt* stmt = nullptr;
            perror(::sqlite3_prepare_v2(db.get(), sql.c_str(), -1, &stmt, 0));

            return { handle(stmt, ::sqlite3_finalize), db };
        }

        int step()            { return ::sqlite3_step(_stmt.get()); }
        int column_int(int c) { return ::sqlite3_column_int(_stmt.get(), c); }
      private:
        using handle = std::shared_ptr<::sqlite3_stmt>;
        database _db; // keeping it around for the lifetime of _stmt
        handle _stmt;

        statement(handle&& h, database& db) : _db(db), _stmt(std::move(h)) { }
    };

    database open(char const* path) {
        ::sqlite3* db = nullptr;
        perror(::sqlite3_open(path, &db));

        return database(db, ::sqlite3_close);
    }

    statement prepare(database db, std::string const& sql) {
        return statement::prepare(db, sql);
    }
}

// FILE: sqliteDB implementation file
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>

void sqliteDB::load() {
    using namespace sqlpp;

    auto stmt = prepare(open("/tmp/database.db"), "SELECT ID, CODE FROM SiteCode;");

    while (stmt.step() == SQLITE_ROW)         
        _records.emplace_back(stmt.column_int(0), stmt.column_int(1));
}

void sqliteDB::writeJson(std::ostream& os) const {
    using namespace boost::property_tree;
    ptree pt;

    for (auto &entry : _records)
        pt.put(std::to_string(entry.id), entry.code);

    write_json(os, pt, false);
}

// FILE: main program
template <typename List>
static void printList(List const& list) {
    int s = list.size();
    std::cout << "The number of Records is: " << s << "\n";

    for (auto& r : list) std::cout << r << " ";
}

void dump(sqliteDB const& db) {
    printList(db.get());
    std::cout << "\n==============[ AS JSON ]===============\n";
    db.writeJson(std::cout);
}

int main() { 
    sqliteDB db;

    std::cout << "before loading: \n";
    dump(db);

    std::cout << "after loading: \n";
    db.load();
    dump(db);
}
```

Just compile as `g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp -lsqlite3` and get:

```
sehe@desktop:/tmp$ sqlite3 database.db <<< "create table SiteCode (id int primary key, code int);"
sehe@desktop:/tmp$ for a in {1..10}; do echo "insert into SiteCode(ID,CODE) VALUES($a, $RANDOM);"; done | sqlite3 database.db 
sehe@desktop:/tmp$ ./test
```

Output

```
before loading: 
The number of Records is: 0

==============[ AS JSON ]===============
{}
after loading: 
The number of Records is: 10
(1,5591) (2,31578) (3,30641) (4,4850) (5,1628) (6,5133) (7,8798) (8,20601) (9,21213) (10,18222) 
==============[ AS JSON ]===============
{"1":"5591","2":"31578","3":"30641","4":"4850","5":"1628","6":"5133","7":"8798","8":"20601","9":"21213","10":"18222"}
```

Comment: whoa. There are so many things for me to absorb. I will get back to you.  and thanks a ton for taking out the time to reply back.

Comment: PS. the main elements I addressed are: object lifetime, exception safety and DRY using RAII (mainly the `shared_ptr` tricks); command/query separation; const-correctness; proper naming; (modularity of code)

Comment: I wish I could have given you 1000 up votes. Your answer is flawless. I modified your answer as per my need and got the desired results. I will be posting my answer tomorrow on this page. I have some follow on questions too.

Answer (score 0):

ok so working on the solution provide above by sehe. i finally able to get the output right. I had to modify his solution as per my need. here the answer is as per below. All credit and thanks to sehe.

Below is my **DBAccess1.h** file:

```
#ifndef DBAccess1_HH
#define DBAccess1_HH

#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <list>   
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

using namespace std;
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
using boost::property_tree::read_json;
using boost::property_tree::write_json;
using boost::property_tree::basic_ptree;

//=========================//
struct SiteCode
{
  int siteID;
  int siteCode;

    friend inline std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, SiteCode const& site) {
    return out << "(" << site.siteID << "," << site.siteCode << ")";
    }
};
//=========================//
class sqliteDB {

using Records = std::list<SiteCode>;
Records Site_Code_list;

public:

list<SiteCode> GET_ALL_Site_Code();
Records const& get() const { return Site_Code_list; }
void writeJson(std::ostream& os) const;
void printList() const;
};

#endif
```

Below is **DBAccess11.cpp**

```
#include <ostream>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

#include "DBAccess1.h"

using boost::property_tree::ptree;
using boost::property_tree::read_json;
using boost::property_tree::write_json;
using boost::property_tree::basic_ptree;

list<SiteCode> sqliteDB::GET_ALL_Site_Code()
{
        sqlite3 *db;
        const char *sql;
        sqlite3_stmt * stmt;

        int rc = sqlite3_open("/path.to/database.db", &db);

        sql = "SELECT * FROM SiteCode;";

        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, 0);

        while(sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_ROW) {

            int A  = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
            int B = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 1);

            SiteCode info;
            info.siteID = A;
            info.siteCode = B;              

            cout<<"Preparing to push data into List"<<endl;
            Site_Code_list.push_back(info);
            cout<<"Data was pushed successfully"<<endl;
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return Site_Code_list;
}
//==============================================================//
void sqliteDB::writeJson(std::ostream& os) const
{
    using namespace boost::property_tree;
    ptree pt;

    for (auto &entry : Site_Code_list)
        pt.put(std::to_string(entry.siteID), entry.siteCode);

    write_json(os, pt, false);
}
//=========================================================//
```

Below is **main.cpp**

```
#include <ostream>

#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

#include "DBAccess1.h"

using namespace std ;
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
using boost::property_tree::read_json;
using boost::property_tree::write_json;
using boost::property_tree::basic_ptree;

template <typename List>
static void printList(List const& list) {
    int s = list.size();
    std::cout << "The number of Records is: " << s << "\n";
    for (auto& r : list) std::cout << r << " ";
}

void dump(sqliteDB const& db) {
    printList(db.get());
    std::cout << "\n==============[ AS JSON ]===============\n";
    db.writeJson(std::cout);
}

int main()
{

    sqliteDB object1;

    std::cout << "before loading: \n";
    dump(object1);

    std::cout << "after loading: \n";
    object1.GET_ALL_Site_Code();
    dump(object1);

    return 0;
}
```

**compiled** the above using:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o main main.cpp DBAccess11.cpp -lsqlite3 -lboost_serialization
```

And the following is the **output** I get:

```
before loading: 
The number of Records is: 0

==============[ AS JSON ]===============
{}
after loading: 
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
Preparing to push data into List
Data was pushed successfully
The number of Records is: 10
(7,786) (8,78) (9,785) (10,998) (11,656) (13,23) (14,7) (15,74) (16,954) (17,752) 
==============[ AS JSON ]===============
{"7":"786","8":"78","9":"785","10":"998","11":"656","13":"23","14":"7","15":"74","16":"954","17":"752"}
```